# How do i get user role details from WhoAmIRequest in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to find whether a user has worked on given case before in `CRM 2011`.

I am trying write unit test to get an user id as follows

```
var userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)_orgservice.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
```

and then trying to get user details as follows:

```
var systemuser = _service.Retrieve(
    "systemuser", 
    user.Id,
    new ColumnSet(true)
);
```

My user stub as follows:

```
var id = new Guid("2974f072-e02a-45e8-b060-4811f24283c0");
SystemUser user = new SystemUser
{
    FirstName = "FirstName_Test",
    LastName = "LastName_Test",
    Id = id
};

return user;
```

When run the test, I see different `UserId`, not the one I set. I am not sure what is going here. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you mocking the `_service` object or calling CRM directly? What is the test case? Perhaps you can post a more complete set of code segments so we can attempt to recreate the issue.

Comment: Yes, I am mocking the `IOrganisationService `, the test case is that the given Case Review  should be assignable only if he assigned to him/her, otherwise review link should be disabled, the method I am writing is take the Review entity and returns boolean value, sorry I am not in work to provide code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [FakeXrmEasy](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy) for unit testing? No need to stub or mock anything... it's already done for you.

That's specially handy for queries, because they might have many different joins, filters, and so on, which would be hard to replicate using your own mocks from scracth. Example [here](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/blob/master/FakeXrmEasy.Tests.Shared/FakeContextTests/TranslateQueryExpressionTests/FakeContextTestTranslateQueryExpression.cs)

For the above example, there is also an implementation of the WhoAmIRequest which will return the user you set in the CallerId property of the context.

[Here's](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/blob/5b89db3da2d5fa0d9d090c77153ee3a06ad0207d/FakeXrmEasy.Tests.Shared/FakeContextTests/WhoAmIRequest/WhoAmITests.cs) an example.

Comment: Just a reminder, if you are recommending a software/product/service to which you are attached you should mention it in your answer - just so people know you are not an unbiased writer.